# Pass a list of values into an emmet generator expression

Tags: html, emmet

I am writing HTML code with the assistance of the emmet toolkit and want to know if there is a way to pass unique text values (predefined as a list of some sort) into an emmet html element generator expression.

```
<!-- Example:  -->

  span.myClass{textValue$}*4

 <!--Will yield:  -->
  <span class="myClass">textValue1</span>
  <span class="myClass">textValue2</span>
  <span class="myClass">textValue3</span>
  <span class="myClass">textValue4</span>

<!--Desired: -->

  textValues = ["as","gh","xc"];

  <!-- Some generator expression, G(textValues), that yields this -->
    <span class="myClass">as</span>
    <span class="myClass">gh</span>
    <span class="myClass">xc</span>
```

I was wondering if there is a built-in method, or clever generator expression that can achieve this.

Comment: http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/

Answer (score 0):

**When you have existing text and you wanted to wrap it with HTML tags**

FYI my example I used CodePen for the wrapping abbreviation for exist body of text some of my examples below and for some I just generated them with the multiplier.

```
textValue
textValue
textValue
textValue
```

**Getting familiar with Emmet commands**

1. Highlight the text
2. Then press (⇧+⌘+A on macOS and ⇧+CTRL+A on Windows)
3. You'll see an input field with "Enter Abbreviation” in a modal
   pop-up

**Example for unordered and list:**

Type this in the "Enter Abbreviation”:

`ul>li*`

or if you wanted to put custom text `{}` or numbers `$` or what have you at the front or at the back of custom text of an unordered list. The ordered list `ol` will give the default numbered list. You could potentially custom text if you wanted and then run a find and replace.

`ul>li{textValue $}*`

It'll come out like this for the example

```
<ul>
    <li>textValue 1</li>
    <li>textValue 2</li>
    <li>textValue 3</li>
    <li>textValue 4</li>
</ul>
```

**Your desired solution**

Type this in the "Enter Abbreviation” for your desired solution to wrap around existing text:

`span.myClass>li*`

For your desired solution to generate custom text with an ordered numbers

`span.myClass{textValue $}*4`

```
<span class="myClass">textValue 1</span>
<span class="myClass">textValue 2</span>
<span class="myClass">textValue 3</span>
<span class="myClass">textValue 4</span>
```

To my knowledge you can create your own Emmet snippets for your own text editor. You can also create your own custom tab triggers in CodePen (check out the link) https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/tab-triggers/

Here's the Emmet Cheat Sheet to bookmark https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/